# Как отключать звук в игре при сворачивание браузера?

Tags: c#, unity3d, webgl

Сделал браузерную игру на Unity WebGL нужно что бы при сворачивании окна с игрой отключался звук. Как это прописать в коде?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FocusSoundController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
    {
        Silence(!hasFocus);
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused)
    {
        Silence(isPaused);
    }

    private void Silence(bool silence)
    {
        AudioListener.pause = silence;
        // Or / And
        AudioListener.volume = silence ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

ответ взят отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707032/unity3d-webgl-mute-the-sound-when-tab-or-browser-inactive